# First commit; commits two transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the code below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
alter PROCEDURE TestProc
AS
BEGIN
    begin try

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --SET XACT_ABORT on;

    set transaction isolation level read committed

    create table #Test (id int)

    begin transaction 
    insert into #Test values (1)
    begin transaction 
    insert into #Test values (2)
    commit
    select * from #test
    commit
    select * from #test
    end try

    begin catch
    print 'got here 1'
    end catch
END
GO
```

which is called by this:

```
begin try
exec TestProc
end try

begin catch
print @@TRANCOUNT
end catch
```

The output is:

```
table 1:
1
2

table 2:
1
2
```

Why does the first commit; commit both transactions? Please see this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4451/SQL-Server-Transactions-and-Error-Handling, which says: "No matter how deeply you nest a set of transactions, only the last COMMIT has any effect.".  I would expect the first table to contain one row only:

```
table 1
1
```

Comment: "only the last COMMIT has any effect" means only the last COMMIT is actually a COMMIT as far as the "outside world" is concerned. It doesn't mean that anything that happens in nested transactions hasn't happened within the scope of the outer transaction.

Comment: Nested transactions in sql server are a myth. They do NOT even come close to what you would expect. Read Paul Randal's blog on the topic. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server is going to parse that like this:

```
begin transaction 
    insert into #Test values (1)
    begin transaction 
        insert into #Test values (2)
    commit
    select * from #test
commit
select * from #test
```

The first `select *` is within the first transaction.  That means it has full access to things already executed previously in that transaction.  Statements executed later in the same transaction have access to uncommitted data as though it were already committed.

Comment: The default isolation level is read committed.  Just to be sure I have added one more statement to my OP i.e. set transaction isolation level read committed.  However, I see the same issue.  Why is it accessing uncommitted data?

Comment: read committed applies to queries that execute from outside the transaction at the same time as the transaction is running, not to queries executed from within the transaction

Comment: @w0051977 It *is* committed *within the context of that transaction*.  If you only run the lines one at a time (and don't use a temp table) and simultaneously in another query window run `select * from MyTestTableName` after each statement, you'll find that the first insert won't be visible until the second `commit` runs.

Comment: @Bacon Bits, of course.  When you commit, all the other processes can see the change, however within the context of your process you see changes as and when they occur.  Thanks.